# Is there a way to get a call graph for certain c++ function in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wonder whether there is a tool for VS that can show me a call graph (that is, a diagram listing all *possible* execution paths) for a given C++ function. It would help in navigating a big code base, in cases where a function is called in only a few places.

For oft-called functions like `printf` it could simply say:

> too many options...

Again I guess it is not really easy to make such tool so I wonder if it exists, but you know it seems possible to do it so you never know... :)

EDIT: I know about find all references, but that gives just call sites of the function, not the call site of the function that called the function that called the function...

EDIT: VS is 2010, but if necessary VS2012 is an option.

Comment: I don't think it's far fetched if all you want is static analysis. Otherwise, with any kind of dynamic dispatch, yeah a pipe dream..

Comment: Debuggers will give you stack tree. Also, take a look at `StackWalk64()` under Windows, you can use it to get stack tree from within your program.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, that wasn't his question.  His question is more orientated towards knowing ahead of time, what call stacks would arrive at a particular function.

Comment: @Moo-Juice You mean, walking _imaginary_ stack by just looking at the source code? I'm confused, compiler can eliminate certain stack frames by inlining, inlining depends on the optimization options, different compilers might inline differently. Bottom line, you have to compile source to talk about call stack. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PetrBudnik Theoretically, if you could analyze the code and know what functions called what other functions - you could then trace your steps back from a particular function and create a stack trace (not a real one, more of a tree) that would show every conceivable way any function *could* be arrived at.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I think, I was confused by terminology. I suppose, you are talking about _call graph_, not _call stack_. [codeviz](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/), for example.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, you're right - I was just repeating the terminology of the OP, but yes - a call graph.

Comment: Try Ndepend http://www.ndepend.com/. I think it has a trial version

Comment: Eclipse CDT is the best in call graph feature, shows it instantly w/o search using a query to its parser DB.

Answer (score 21):

You mentioned that you know about finding all the references. Have you looked into viewing the `Call Hierarchy`? It's probably not your "dream method" but it does allow you to look at a function in terms of "calls to" and "calls from" the given function. The window also allows you to add multiple functions to view in a tree format. So basically you would tree up or down through the possible outcomes.

> Right click on the desired method ( could be anywhere in the hierarchy ) =>
>
> Select "View Call Hierarchy"
>
> Note that if you can add more than one reference point to the window. Delete when needed
>
> You could also use Ctrl+K or Ctrl+T

---

Another fine example, IMHO, of a disappointment in the differences between C++ and C# with VS. I think [Code Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj739835.aspx) would be just what you're looking for. Assuming of course you were working with Ultimate - but nope, not with C++.

Comment: Also works in VS2015, this is syntactical not textual, like some other answers.

Answer (score 12):

There's no such feature in C++/MSVC, as far as I know.

However, there's AQTime profiler for windows that has "static analysis" option that (IF I remember correctly) scans compiled executable, generates call graph and shows you unreacheable functions.

If I remember correctly, AQtime integrates into visual studio (professional edition, afaik).

Unfortunately, this is a commercial profiler that costs around $500, and this feature is not available in trial version. Last time I used static analysis was 3..4 years ago and I don't exactly remember details at the moment (and I don't have access to AQTime anymore). Anyway, it is a specialized tool, so I wouldn't recommend buying it unless you're optimizing code for speed 24/7.

Perhaps, by googling "static analysis", "code coverage" or researching other profilers you'll find somewhat similar tool that does the job for free.

Aside from that, doxygen can generate callgraphs for C++ code. In case of doxygen, you'll have to hunt for functions that are never called yourself.

Also, Visual Studio 2008 had a built-in caller graph feature (which, I think, uses intellisense). Basically, you right click any function and select "show callers" (or something like that), that'll open list of all functions (visual studio THINKS are calling your function) in a window. Because this feature was present in VS2008, it should be included in VS2010. However, it can't detect every caller for obvious reasons (virtual methods, callbacks, etc).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe doxygen is the tool you are looking for. It provides the possibility to generate call graphs (showing all functions called by a specific function) and/or caller graphs(showing the functions that the function is directly or indirectly called by).

see: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html

Comment: I also can only recommend doxygen. Configured this can give you a html browsable document with all call-graphs. Afaik there is also the possibility to include doxygen-created documentation in VS. The graphs will be drawn by graphviz and it really helps getting a grip at big code bases.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Understand tool (http://www.scitools.com). It's great for drawing call graphs and control flow charts.Unfortunately, it's commercial.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve results after doing Symbol search. Just right click in your source and then select find all references that performs symbol search. Its explained in further details at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/17/improvements-to-find-all-references-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: The result graph is textual rather than tautologically sorted diagram and requires getting used to, for eg. Right-click on symbol to find refs rather than shift focus amongst visual vertices for navigation along edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can  try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) which give you the call graph inside VS and provides many features in its dependency graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Source Navigator is a tool that I have used and have been quite happy with on C++ projects. Again, it is not within the Visual Studio IDE, but it has some great advantages if you don't mind pressing Alt-Tab :-)

- works with both C and C++ sources
- is quite fast in it's indexing and searching; it's a pleasure to use, IMHO
- is a visual tool
- is a free and Open Source tool

See http://sourcenav.berlios.de/screenshots/ for some screenshots

In particular, you are looking for the [Cross-Reference Browser](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/online-docs/userguide/crossref.html):

> "It can find every call of a function, or tell you everything a
>   particular function calls. It creates tree diagrams that show
>   essential relationships within the project's symbol database, such as
>   the function call hierarchy tree. You can traverse up and down the
>   hierarchy tree, as well as expand or restrict the tree. You can select
>   items in the hierarchy and display their Refers-to and Referred-by
>   relationships; these relationships are based on the "point-of-view" of
>   the selected symbol."

Though this example screenshot from the tutorial, ["Using the Cross-Reference Browser"](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/online-docs/userguide/tutorial.html#pgfId-1223096) shows Referred-by relationships (using red arrows) for a class and not a function, the latter use case would be very similar. You can also browse what functions / methods are getting called from a function, and that would be a Refers-to relationship, shown using blue arrows instead of red.

[image]

Do give it a try! As I mentioned before, I have been a happy user of this tool; it's not very well-known, but is a good piece of software (that also stands as an example for how useful Tcl/Tk can be in the right hands).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use VS Plugin - CodeGraph on your solution and look for the specific function you are looking for and go on from there. It does static analysis on your solution and generates a nice graph of the call flows. Check "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YaobinOuyang.CodeAtlas". Hope this helps.