# C# Find Path From Function A To Function B

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

Using static code analysis and not debugging, I want to input a **start function** and an **end function**. The output should be the **path of functions** or stacktrace that can get me from start function to end function.

Any ideas how to do this or of preexisting tools that do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, than this would be what the "Call Hierarchy" tool window does in Visual Studio 2015+. just that you need to navigate from "start" to "end" by yourself, there is no way to ask intellisense for a path (or non-existence of the same) from two given methods. [somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16190058/1132334), for C++ though.

Comment: you can view the stacktrace of the application with Environment.StackTrace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx . It should contains all related informations you need

Comment: @user1519979: how does `Environment.StackTrace` help someone who has a `start-function` and an `end-function` to get the whole path of functions between? OP doesn't want to execute that code.

Comment: Correct I want to do this with executing any code. @dlatikay does the "Call Hierachy" work with referenced dlls that are not in the same project as well?

Comment: to make a call hierarchy tree without executing . probably the library Microsoft.CodeAnalysis could help you..

Comment: I just checked and it works with referenced assemblies if the source code of those assemblies is available (in a project that is part of the same solution).

Comment: @user1519979 yes [looks promising](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.findsymbols.symbolcallerinfo?view=roslyn-dotnet) but you cannot query a from..to path. You would need to make a `FindSymbols` call to query the references of `start function` and repeatedly call to traverse the tree until you encounter `end function`. in the worst case (`end function` not in call tree of `start function` at all) this would result in a full calling tree traversal of one symbol.

Comment: @dlatikay yes i know, it would be much work to implement a well doing logic for a correct hierarchy tree. don't know any libs for that, but If you find something, let me know. would be interested in a solution too